# margin:auto not working in IE

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center an image inside a `div` tag which works fine on chrome but not on IE...

below is my html code:

```
 <div  id="prod2" class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item custom">
    <a href="#"  class="hvr-bounce-in" data-toggle="modal">
       <img src="img/portfolio/prod2.jpg"  class="img-responsive img-responsive-cust" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="#"   class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
        <h4>Enterprise Portal</h4>
    </a>

</div>
```

below is my css:

```
#prod2{
       background-color:#1FA4B6;
       margin-left:3%
      }
.img-responsive-cust{ 
           display: block;
           margin: auto;
           text-align:center;
           max-width: 70%;
           max-height:70%; 
           padding: 10%;
}
```

I am yet not good at css...Please Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: What version of IE are you having issues with? Working for me in IE9+.